# How to change button background color on click?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-button, android-jetpack-compose-button

How do I change the background color of a button on click?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can do it like this using versions 1.0.0 and later:

```
@Composable
fun ButtonColor() {

    val selected by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Button(colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
            backgroundColor = if (selected) Color.Blue else Color.Gray),

            onClick = { selected = !selected }) {

    }
}
```

For a situation where your color changes back when you release your button, try this:

```
@Composable
fun ButtonColor() {

    val color by remember { mutableStateOf(Color.Blue) }

    Button(
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
            backgroundColor = color
        ),

        onClick = {},

        content = {},

        modifier = Modifier.pointerInteropFilter {
            when (it.action) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                    color = Color.Yellow }

                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP  -> {
                    color = Color.Blue }
            }
            true
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: This is close to what I am looking. But Color should retain back to default when button click release event happens.

Comment: Ok, I've added a solution for that case.

Comment: Should use `by` instead of `=` to skip using `.value` every time.

Comment: I edited the answer and changed the `=` to `by`.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I removed all the ```.value``` as well, otherwise it might be confusing.

Answer (score 46):

If you want to change the background color only when the `Button` is pressed you can use the [**`MutableInteractionSource`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/interaction/MutableInteractionSource.html) and the **`collectIsPressedAsState()`** property.

Something like:

```
val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
val isPressed by interactionSource.collectIsPressedAsState()

// Use the state to change the background color
val color = if (isPressed) Color.Blue else Color.Yellow

Column() {
    Button(
        onClick = {},
        interactionSource = interactionSource,
        colors= ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = color)
    ){
        Text(
         "Button"
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

If you want to achieve a toggle button you can use something like:

```
var selected by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
val color = if (selected) Color.Blue else Color.Yellow

Button(
    onClick = { selected = !selected },
    colors= ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = color)
    ){
        Text("Button")
}
```

[image]

Comment: A nitpicky problem with this is that it won't change color with really quick clicks if the button is in a scrollable container, because of the fix for this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/203141462

Comment: Its madness there isn't just a simple parameter like `colorOnTouchDown`

Comment: Thanks, mine was not working and your answer helped me. My code was missing the interactionSource = interactionSource assignment in the Button and after adding that it started working!

Answer (score 0):

In jetpack compose such an effect should implemented by using [interactionResource](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/touch-input/handling-interactions) here's a simple example.

```
@Composable
fun MyButton(){
val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
val isPressed by interactionSource.collectIsPressedAsState()
val bgcolor = if (isPressed) Color.Red else Color.White
val borderColor = if (isPressed) Color.White else Color.Red

OutlinedButton(
    onClick = {
    }, modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(40.dp),
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
    border = BorderStroke(1.dp, borderColor),
    interactionSource = interactionSource,
    colors = ButtonDefaults.outlinedButtonColors(backgroundColor = bgcolor)
) {
    Text(text = "button", color=borderColor)
}
```

}